# Equivelant of .exec() for regular expressions in VB.Net

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, match

In other languages, specifically JavaScript, there is a .exec() method for regular expressions. I'm very new to VB.NET's RegEx, and I'm not sure whether .Match() is equivelant to .exec(). Also, is the VB.NET RegEx a subset of Perl's regular expressions?

Comment: What do you want to do? I'm not well-versed in .NET's regex API, but I think it should be able to do whatever that can do with JS exec. .NET regex is neither a subset or superset of Perl's regex. They have similarities but they are a flavor of their own. You must re-read the documentation to make sure you know what you are doing - for example `\d`, `\w`, etc. in .NET matches Unicode characters by default.

Comment: You'd probably do best to ask the second question separately.

Comment: MSDN's .NET regular expression documentation at [http://bit.ly/1CytYgu](http://bit.ly/1CytYgu), says that:

"In the .NET Framework, regular expression patterns are defined by a special syntax or language, which is compatible with Perl 5 regular expressions and adds some additional features such as right-to-left matching."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Match` and `exec` are approximately equivalent, yes. You can tell by looking at their respective documentation pages: [JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) / [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match.aspx). Note that both return an entry for each subgroup matched, not entries for each match in the string as a whole.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if I didn't word the question very well, this is my first question on Stack Overflow.